# Quick - Maybe Question on changing gears

Tags: gears

Not looking for a overly technical answer here just a very simplistic one I quess.. When switching gears is it best to try and keep both front and rear gears either high or low (Depending) I mean we wouldn't want say front low and rear high or other way around would we ?

Thanks

Comment: That is a true statement, and is known as cross-chain shifting.  It's harder on the components and can cause mis-shifts.

Comment: Mike - this is a reasonable question and certainly one that occurs to many riders as they get a bit more serious.  However it has already been asked and answered, so this question will likely be closed as a duplicate.  Don't take this closure in any bad way, its not meant to offend.   There's a decent corpus of questions on the site, so browse around.  I'm still learning things.

Answer (score 0):

On most bikes you typically just need to avoid the two most extreme cross-chaining scenarios: (A) the largest front chainring and the largest rear cog and (B) the smallest front chainring and the smallest rear cog.